# Designing a layout for a widget

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Can someone guide me as to how to design a layout for a widget as shown in the attached image

1. The starred portion would be a thumbnail image of a celebrity
2. The portion above and below the diagonal divider "/" should have
   separate listeners.

Can someone please let me the best and efficient way to design this layout?

Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Of course there are a lot of possible solutions. One easy one is:

- utilize a standard ListView
- let a custom adapter (extend BaseAdapter for this purpose) fill each row
- the layout for a list item should use a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation
- create a custom widget only for the "/" divider
- in the layout for a list item put an ImageView (for the celeb picture) and add as menu of your custom "/" widgets you need

For your custom widget I suggest to extend an existing Android widget instead of buildung one from scratch. To extend a FrameLayout might be a good solution because you can have a recangular background which is overlayed by a triangular overlay. With an onTouchListener you can detect which of them is clicked.

This way the effort of creating such widget would be minimized by the use of as much standard solutions as possible.

Here is one abstract example implementation of your custom widget:

```
    public class DividedView extends FrameLayout implements OnTouchListener {
          public void onCreate(Context context, AttributeSet attr){
              View firstView =  createFirstView();

              View secondView = createSecondView(); //this view has a triangle shape but with a transparent buttom-right corner... but the boundaries match the complete size of this custom widget... therefore this view consumes all touch events
              secondView.setOnTouchListener(this);

              addView(firstView);
              addView(secondView);
          }

          ...

          public boolean onTouch(MotionEvent event){
              switch(event.getAction(){
                   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    //detect if coordinates of touch down are in boundaries of first or second view... if yes trigger click event for firstView or secondView depending on coordinates
                    break;
              }
          }

          //via this method you can set corresponding click listener for each of the divided views
          public void setFirstViewOnClickListener(OnClickListener onClickListener)
          ...

    }
```

Comment: ***To extend a FrameLayout might be a good solution because you can have a recangular background which is overlayed by a triangular overlay*** Instead of doing this with java code, can I define this in xml and use it in java code?

Comment: Please tell me more of the behaviour you want to achieve. Of course it's possible to design everthing in XML and reference it in your code. For instance in my example above I did not further specify the methods createFirstView(), createSecondView(). In these methods you may of course inflate the concrete layout from XML. When you only need the distinction if the user clicked on the upper-left or the bottom-right part you can design everything in XML and only need to assign the onTouchListener for the distinction of the click event. So please tell me more and I will update my answer :-)